# Is it possible to import an .png in a drawing made with pst-3dplot?

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

I would like to make a drawing using pst-3dplot with a .png embedded in it. Does anybody know if this is possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you can, most likely using `\includegraphics`.